# ActiveMQ http connection refused

Tags: java, http, activemq-classic, connect

I am trying to connect my java client application to ActiveMQ over http, but keep getting an error:

```
Failed to perform GET on: http://localhost:8080 as response was: Connection refused: connect
```

This connections works why I connect with: tcp://localhost:61616

activemq.xml

```
<broker>
  ...
  <transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8080"/>
  </transportConnectors>
  ...
</broker>
```

jndi.properties in my Java Client program:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
#java.naming.provider.url = tcp://localhost:61616
java.naming.provider.url = http://localhost:8080
connectionFactoryNames = connectionFactory, queueConnectionFactory, topicConnectionFactry
queue.testQueue = testQueue
```

Java Client

```
package be.jmshub.jmsremotejndiproducer;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Producer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: start");

        try {
            // create a new intial context, which loads from jndi.properties file
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("connectionFactory");
            Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
            Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup("testQueue");
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

            System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: connected");

            int count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                String messageText = "This is message " + (i + 1);
                Message message = session.createTextMessage(messageText);
                System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: sending - " + messageText);
                producer.send(message);
                count += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: total messages sent: " + count);

            // Clean up
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: EXCEPTION:" + ex.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("JMS REMOTE PRODUCER: finished");
    }
}
```

This works with tcp://localhost:61616 but not with http://localhost:8080

Can any person help me get this thing up and running?

Comment: have you tried some other port? 8081

Comment: 8081 gives the same problem: Failed to perform GET on: http://localhost:8081 as response was: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Comment: How do you start your broker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below a stripped down example to start the broker. Your `Producer` runs without any problem.

**activemq.xml**

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" start="false">
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:0?maximumConnections=1000"/>
            <transportConnector name="http" uri="http://0.0.0.0:8080"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

**Broker.java**

```
package be.jmshub.jmsremotejndiproducer;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;

public class Broker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker("xbean:foo.xml");
        broker.setPersistent(false);
        broker.start();
        broker.waitUntilStarted();
    }
}
```